# launch multiple processes in bash with for loop

Tags: bash, ubuntu

On ubuntu, I'm trying to launch multiple instances of filebeat on the same host using a for loop but I encounter a weird behavior

The command I'm trying to launch

```
for i in `seq 1 2` ; do /etc/filebeat-test/filebeat-$i/filebeat &  done
```

And the error message I get and then when I exit the command:

```
Exiting: error loading config file: stat filebeat.yml: no such file or directory
^C
[1]-  Termine 1               /etc/filebeat-test/filebeat-$i/filebeat
[2]+  Termine 1               /etc/filebeat-test/filebeat-$i/filebeat
```

It looks like $i is not interpreted..

The weird thing is that I had this command working a couple of times, but 2 seconds later it won't work. I also tried to launch it from a file and to replace $i with "$i" with the same result.

Any idea what is going on?
Thanks for your help

Comment: you need to add parenthesis `do ( few commands & parmeters ) & ; done ` I think is some cases you also need a bash env for each job then it becomes `do ( bash ( few commands & params ) ) & ; done `    being careful with variables & escape chars when needed in that case

Comment: This has less to do with the path to `filebeat`, and more to do with the lack of a findable `filebeat.yml` for *any* instance, let alone (presumably) a separate one for each instance.

Comment: @francoisP, I have the same issue while running the command with your syntax.

Comment: @chepner. If I run the command without a for loop (/etc/filebeat-test/filebeat-1/filebeat) It is working fine, So the path to filebeat.yml doesn't seem to be the issue. Plus It doesn't explain why I had the command working a couple of time. But you are right in a way, as it seems to find the binary but not the unique conf file per instance

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```sh
# set -x # uncomment this to see what actually happens while the lopp cycles
for i in `seq 1 2` ; do (/etc/filebeat-test/filebeat-$i/filebeat &);  done
```